# Javascript get context of function

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

There is some JavaScript I want to debug (e.g. make something which was written for Ext JS 4 work with Ext JS 3). And there is function `define`, which is absent in version 3. I wanted just paste it's code, but don't know where it lies. I printed it:

```
>>> Ext.define.toString()
"function (i, j, h) { if (j.override) { return a.createOverride.apply(a, arguments); } return a.create.apply(a, arguments); }"
```

But still, I don't know what is `a`. How could I, having function object get the source for context of that object?

Comment: It's JavaScript: you can just read the source code, can't you?

Comment: You could also try to use `Ext.define` and then step into it using debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You may update your ExtJS 3 to latest version. In ExtJS 3.4.1.1, which is the latest version of ExtJS you can download from Sencha website [here](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs3/download/).

As it was introduced in ExtJS 3.4.0 (once ExtJS 4 was out), the behaviour must be near the same, so maybe you will require less changes in the code to make it work with ExtJS 3

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from: https://extjs-public.googlecode.com/svn/extjs-4.x/include/ext-dev.js

```
define: function (className, data, createdFn) {
        Ext.classSystemMonitor && Ext.classSystemMonitor(className, 'ClassManager#define', arguments);

        if (data.override) {
            return Manager.createOverride.apply(Manager, arguments);
        }

        return Manager.create.apply(Manager, arguments);
    },
```

Apparently, your `a` is `Manager`. I doubt if this helps to move `define` to Ext 3 but here you go :)